# Handle click a button or undeline text in webview react_native

Tags: react-native

I need 1 feature as follows: Click a button or underline text in my webview and console this click. example : [image]
Click "Xem chi tiết" => show a alert "you clicked xemchitiet".
XemChitiet is a "href" or "button" or "element tag html". This my code:

`<WebView
        source={{html: '<h1>Xem lí thuyết các loại nhiễm điện</h1><a style=\"text-decoration:underline\">Xem chi tiết</a>'}}
      />`

Answer (score 0):

You need a React-Webview bridge to accomplish that, take look into [react-native-webview-bridge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-webview-bridge).

Comment: Serdar, I need click in web view, not a component, hjxxx

Comment: Sorry, I've misunderstood the question, I've edited my answer accordingly, hope it helps.